# Finding weights of predictive variables in regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, pca, weighted-regression

**Question:**
How to calculate and add weights to each predictive variable (so that these weights represent the importance of the predictive variable in measuring the regression score)?

For example, we have scorings of documents (Response variable), obtained through functional expertise opinion, given categorical variables. An example data set would be:

- Variables: Doc_type , Doc_subtype, Topic, Scoring
- Example of a registry: “magazine”, “sport_review”, “soccer”, 120

I have thought of several forms of resolving this question:

1. Use a simple correlation plot and watch the correlated values of predictive variables against response variable (score).
2. Do a Principal Component Analysis and then do a Varimax rotation and watch the correlation in each dimension against the response variable.
3. Base the weights of the parameters of the regression in functional expertise (the opinion of an expert that has years of experience in this field).

What approach do you think is the best to find the variables weights in the regression? Naturally, it does not need to be one of the ones I have proposed above. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This post looks like it's just a dump of notes to yourself.  I'd suggest trying to restructure this to ask some more concrete questions. You'll likely get much better (or even any) responses if you do that.

Comment: @Analyst1 I appreciate your feedback. I will reestructure the question. I thought that if I showed all my knowledge and possible solutions to my problem, it would be easier for more experienced members to answer.

Comment: no problem. I'm not trying to be critical, but just trying to help you get some useful answers.  There is nothing wrong with showing your thought process.  In fact, it's encouraged.  I would maybe just put some of your "notes"/"thoughts" under an "Additional Info" header or something.  Then I'd really try to focus on what specific question you are trying to answer in a more structured and direct way.